# How to use generic programming with a GUI?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have developed a big program using techniques of generic programming, which involve lots of class templates. Is there anyway to simulate choosing these parameters at runtime based on GUI options?

Say I have a

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class MyClass {};
```

and I want to choose A, B, and C from 3 groups of radio buttons. Without making a combinatorially long switch statement, is there any way to instantiate MyClass using the types that the user selects in the GUI?

Comment: Unfortunately not; absolutely every template parameter must be known at compile time.

Comment: Template classes are instantiated during compilation. So you have to instantiate all possible combinations and then simply select a proper one based on user's input.

Comment: Why are these comments and not answers?

Comment: Because "No you can't" is not the answer that the OP would gladly accept :)

Comment: @AzzA - is there an "automatic" way to do this? If I have 5 choices for each parameter, I don't want to have a 125 case conditional!

Comment: @DavidDoria templates are not the right tool for the job you're doing :)

Comment: @DavidDoria Looking at the Qt tags in your question, you are also glossing over the fact that QObject cannot be used within templates.  So even if you were to create a templated model - you still couldn't use it for Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert here, but I do believe that as others mentioned in comments that this isn't possible.

What you *could* perhaps do is write a GUI application that changed parameters in a template file, and kicked off the compilation and execution of this project.  We often do similar things in order to unit test our code with different compilation targets/environments, and that sounds like essentially what you are trying to do.

Comment: It would be hilarious to have a user recompile the source code every time he started the application.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - Ah, yeah if he intends this to be done by the end user that's a bad idea.  I read it more as a unit testing problem where he wants to test a bunch of different possibilities, along the lines of dependency injection.  If this is user facing then yeah, don't do what I said ;).

Comment: Haha yea, it is for the end user. @SethCarnegie - so people rant and rave about generic programming but don't ever consider the possibility that someone will want to write a GUI on top of it? That just seems like a huge disconnect to me.

Comment: @DavidDoria almost by definition, setting GUI options and stuff is done at runtime. Generic programming is definitely awesome, but it's not for runtime things. It's basically for writing libraries. Complaining that you can't accomplish GUI programming with templates is a bit like saying that functional programming sucks because you can't have a program with state, or that coffee sucks because you can't use it to fly; it's _made_ to be that way, and it's not the right tool for _everything_ you'll ever need to do.

Comment: @DavidDoria: That's a really bizarre argument there... that's like saying that "people rant and rave about the iPhone but don't ever consider the possibility that someone will make cherry pie with it". Well, no, they don't. They expect you to use flour and cherries to make a pie.

Comment: @KerrekSB - He may have used a bit of hyperbole, but I think his basic point is sound.  This is simply not the tool for the job he wants to do.  It was never designed to be.